# Xcode 7 supporting watch OS1 and OS2

Tags: ios, xcode7, watchos-2, watchos

I have been fiddling with Xcode 7 for sometime now, I get to know that it supports only Swift 2 and there is no way to support Swift 1.0 or 1.2 in Xcode 7. This is fine.

Now coming to WatchOS, can I have two targets one for WatchOS1 and one for WatchOS2 separately in Xcode 7 so that I can support for both??

I was looking into the deployment target setting in the build settings of both the watch target and the iOS app target but I could see only WatchOS2 in the list so

1. **Can I support two targets one for WatchOS1 & WatchOS2 respectively in Xcode 7? If so should I install WatchOS1 SDK at some place?? or
   this it totally not possible, if not why?.**
2. **If both targets can be supported how can I prevent source duplicates for both targets since both OS have significant
   differences in terms of architecture.**
3. **Also since the introduction of WatchConnectivity framework the iOS counterpart app will also have some changes, how to maintain that
   for the two targets?**

I am confused and I need to take a decision quickly, any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Droppy But in iOS targets I am able to see lower version of iOS in the list. Why so?

Comment: @Droppy Yes I too think the same but what if I need to support both, fingers crossed!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can support watchOS 1 apps in Xcode 7.
You can also support watchOS 2 apps in Xcode 7.

If you want to support both watchOS 1 and watchOS 2 then you will need to have separate targets for each OS (due to the differences in architecture)

For a watchOS 1 app, add a new target and select the **Apple Watch** section from the left and then click on the **WatchKit App for watchOS 1** from the list.

[image: watchOS 1 App]

For a watchOS 2 app, add a new target and select the **watchOS** > **Application** section and then click on the **WatchKit App** option in the list.

[image: watchOS 2 App]

Couple of things to note about making a watchOS 1 app in Xcode 7 (beta 1)...

Because I did my testing on an iPhone 6 running iOS 8.3 and my watch running watchOS 1.0.1, I needed to change my deployment target to iOS 8.3 but note that you want to do this at a project level rather than just target level (so that the extension also gets set to 8.3 and not just the main app) otherwise it won't let you deploy onto a real device.

Due to a known issue in Xcode 7 beta 1, a watchOS 1 app will fail to install on a real watch with the following error if your paired phone is 64 bit:

```
Jun 20 17:25:08 Liams-iPhone companionappd[271] <Notice>: (Error) WatchKit: validateWatchKitApplicationInfoDictionary, invalid Info.plist key 'UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities'
```

This is because Xcode 7 is adding arm64 to the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` info.plist key at build time even to your watchOS 1 extension when it shouldn't be.

You can temporarily get around this by setting **Build Active Architecture Only** to `NO` for DEBUG mode.

[image: Xcode 7 Known Issue]

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks liam for the detailed answer but I have few questions please se my updated question.

Comment: How exactly do you test the watchos1 app? As I don't see an option to download watchos1 simulator

Comment: I'm not sure about simulators but I know that you are able to run it on a physical device running watchOS 2.x

Answer (score 4):

You can have both a watchOS 2 app for an iOS 9 iPhone and a watchKit Extension for an iOS 8 device.

I would though say that if you haven't already made a WatchKit app (as in watchOS 1), then it's highly unproductive to make a watchOS 2 app and try to create and maintain a watchOS 1 app... just jump on board to watchOS 2 for sanity purposes!

Comment: No @Daniel I already have a WatchKit 1 app and I want to take a stand due to release dates.

Comment: So the watch engineers encouraged me at WWDC to not "migrate" my watchOS 1 app to 2, instead just create a new target for the watchOS 2 app and have them coexist.

Comment: Ok makes sense but any idea on how to juggle code for the two targets?

Comment: You could remove os1 specific API usage in your interface controllers to a category or separate class and then use that slimmed down interface controller class in both targets. My app will probably be completely rewritten so I don't have this concern but that's probably how I would do it.

Comment: Xcode 7: Has anyone seen where the dropdown for  the deployment target for the watch kit 1.0 app and extension ONLY has watch kit 2.0 available?  Tried an existing and a new project and same result for the WK1.0 targets.  I did set the associated iOS app to 8.3 target, still no luck.  Must I extract the 1.0 WK SDK from an earlier version of Xcode?  Wondering if anyone's done it.

Comment: @rholmes did you finally manage to build your watchos1 app under Xcode7 . I have a problem similar.