# The os version installed on apple watch does not support the watchkit app prodct

Tags: apple-watch, watchos-2, xcode7-beta4

I am using Xcode 7. My apple watch app works fine in the simulator. It also can be successfully built on device. However, the app seems not to be installed neither on iPhone 5 or apple watch (1.0).

The iPhone and watch pair is ineligible. And it states "The OS version installed on apple watch does not support watchkit app product. I tried everything in [SwampThingTom's Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881528/cant-install-watchkit-app-on-apple-watch), but I still change the status of the phone-watch pair. The app on phone without watch works well. The problem only comes when watch is included to test app on watch. Does it mean something is wrong with apple watch?

I am new in app developing. Can anyone help me? I appreciate any help.

Comment: I found the answer here in the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974685/xcode-7-supporting-watch-os1-and-os2). @liamnichols gave the answer right to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you marked your question with watch-os-2, it is possible that this is correct and you develop against watch OS 2.

If this is the case: you can't run a watch OS 2 app on watch OS 1.

I see to ways to tolve this:

You could set your development target to iOS 8.x and Watch OS 2.

Or you could wait a few weeks until you can install the new OS version on your devices. Since developing for watch OS 2 is much more fun I'd suggest the latter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Gerd.