# Support Watch OS 1.0 and 2.0 thows error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, watchos

I have an app and WatchOS 2.0 app. While I want the app to support lower version of the watch also.

Tried this [Xcode 7 supporting watch OS1 and OS2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974685/xcode-7-supporting-watch-os1-and-os2)

But I get this error.

> This app contains multiple WatchKit 2.0 apps. Only a single WatchKit 2.0 app is allowed.

I am totally confused by the error because the error says I have 2 apps of Watch OS 2.0 While one of my target is for WatchOS 1.

[image]

How do I solve this issue and support all the watch OS.

I use Xcode 7.3.